# Async function not working inside UseEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, async-await, react-hooks

I am creating an async function inside the useEffect callback. But because of some reason, every time component renders, I can only see the output from the first console. And execution control never goes inside the async function. Thus returning empty array at the end.

```
const [targets, setTargets] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside UseEffect"); //logs the output
    (async () => {
        var url = `https://xx.yy.zz/?param={"request_type":"query_osm_circle","lat":${region.latitude},"lng":${region.longitude},"radius":3,"limit":10}`;
        try {
            let response = await fetch(
                url,
            );
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson); //does not log the output
            setTargets(responseJson);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    })
});
console.log(targets); //returns empty array
```

Comment: You are not invoking your function inside the useEffect. You should put an empty dep array for your useEffect (if you want it to run only once) and before that invoke your created function.

Comment: you need to call it, like: `(async () => { ... })()` note that last `()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Inside UseEffect"); //logs the output
     (async () => {
         var url = `https://xx.yy.zz/?param={"request_type":"query_osm_circle","lat":${region.latitude},"lng":${region.longitude},"radius":3,"limit":10}`;
         try {
             let response = await fetch(
                 url,
             );
             let responseJson = await response.json();
             console.log(responseJson); //does not log the output
             setTargets(responseJson);
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error);
         }
     })()
 },[]);
```